# Are the words in "The 40th-anniversary restoration of the concert film" really in the right order? Is this semantical?

Tags: meaning, word-order, nouns

> The 40th-anniversary restoration of the concert film is a funk spectacle. It has also united the band, which split up in 1991, to discuss the landmark. — [NYT](https://www.nytimes.com/2023/09/09/arts/music/talking-heads-stop-making-sense.html)

For someone learning English, the phrase "The 40th-anniversary restoration of the concert film is a funk spectacle" is really confusing. I mean is "40th-anniversary" describing the noun "restoration" by the order of words it feels like it, so it would make a restoration of the "40th-anniversary" does that make sense?

Comment: A restoration done for the 40th anniversary.

Comment: "The 40th-anniversary restoration of the concert film is a funk spectacle" is a bit awkward because the initial noun phrase ("The 40th-anniversary restoration of the concert film") is very long, and in casual writing or speech you normally try and avoid very long noun phrases, especially at the start of sentences (something like "They discussed the 40th-anniversary restoration of the concert film" would avoid that problem.)

Comment: "Semantical" [is a word](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/semantical), but it has a different meaning from what you seem to intend.

Answer (score 2):

They're not restoring the 40th anniversary, they're restoring the concert film, 40 years on.
This, therefore, makes perfect sense.

The restoration of a 40-year-old film is the '40th-anniversary restoration'.

Film restoration - cleaning up the sparkles, pops and crackles to make a new, clean version - is big business these days. It always works best when they can tie it to a whole decade, and better still if they can claim involvement by the original artist, meaning they can describe it as an *n*-anniversary celebration, rather than just a commercial opportunity to re-sell something many people had forgotten ever existed.

Comment: Isn't your phrase "40-year old" correct as "40 year-old" or "40-year-old"? Because I think that is what the OP missed, the hyphen in 40th-anniversary, as per my answer.

Comment: Yup. Missed a hyphen. Thanks, fixed :)